# Segmentation Fault using pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am creating a simple program that open a *.rgba* file and rotate it.
Compiling with `gcc code.c -o x -lm -lpthread` , I got 'Segmentation fault' after running `./x img.rgba 90`. Debugging with gdb, the crash occurs in *pthread_create()*, but I don't know why. Removing *pthread_join()*, segfault disappeared, but the logic became wrong.

```
#define WIDTH  512
#define HEIGHT 512
#define NUM_THREADS 16
#define WIDTH_BLOCK 1

unsigned int img_orig [HEIGHT][WIDTH];
unsigned int img_rot [HEIGHT][WIDTH];
int nlin = 0;
int ncol = 0;

typedef struct {
    int i_start;
    int i_end;
    int j_start;
    int j_end;
    int * xc;
    int * yc;
    float * s;
    float * c;
} thread_arg;

void *thread_func(void * arg) {
    // do some logic
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...

    memset(img_rot, 0, WIDTH * HEIGHT * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < nlin; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < ncol; j++)
            read(fd, &img_orig[i][j], 4);
    close(fd);
    xc = ncol / 2;
    yc = nlin / 2;

    angle = angle * M_PI / 180.0;
    s = sin(angle);
    c = cos(angle);
    int step = HEIGHT / NUM_THREADS;

    for (i = 0; i < nlin; i += step) {
        for (j = 0; j < ncol ; j += WIDTH / WIDTH_BLOCK) {
            thread_arg * arg = (thread_arg *) malloc(sizeof(thread_arg));
            arg->i_start = i;
            arg->i_end = i + step;
            arg->j_start = j;
            arg->j_end = j + (WIDTH / WIDTH_BLOCK);
            arg->xc = &xc;
            arg->yc = &yc;
            arg->s = &s;
            arg->c = &c;

            // inicia a thread
            if (pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, thread_func, arg))
                printf("Error");

        }
    }
    // aguarda todas threads acabarem
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post contains `...` and other missing code. Please post real and complete code that can reproduce the problem - read [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The problem is usually found in the `...` part. Or in `// do some logic`

Comment: I think the problem is in the code in the post, all other parts can be removed and the code continue to segfault.

Comment: Then post the code which is compilable and still exhibiting the problem.

Comment: okay, you can see all the code in https://cdn.notepad.pw/fq2d81qr.txt

Comment: How much more clearly do we have to say it? Construct a complete but minimal code that anyone can run exactly as shown to reproduce the problem and add it to the post. Not a full code dump. Not an external link.

Comment: What does the declaration of threads look like?

Comment: @kaylum It's my second time here, I will read the guides.Try to be more friendly.

Comment: @cup It's like pthread_t threads[16];, and it have a problem. Erdal Küçük highlighted it, but the problem still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'nlin' is initialized with 'HEIGHT' (512) and you access your 'threads' array with the index 'i', which depends on 'nlin'. How big is your 'threads' array again?

Comment: Hi! It's size is 16.

Comment: And since when is 16 greater than 512? Your max 'i' musn't be greater than 15!

Comment: Well noted! For sure it's one of the bugs. I have fixed this by replacing thread[i] with thread[i/step] but the problem continues.

Comment: The problem was solved removing the second loop and changing the index used in thread[i] to thread[i/step] in the main loop. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < nlin; i += step) {
    for (j = 0; j < ncol ; j += WIDTH / WIDTH_BLOCK) {
        thread_arg * arg = (thread_arg *) malloc(sizeof(thread_arg));
        arg->i_start = i;
        arg->i_end = i + step;
        arg->j_start = j;
        arg->j_end = j + (WIDTH / WIDTH_BLOCK);
        arg->xc = &xc;
        arg->yc = &yc;
        arg->s = &s;
        arg->c = &c;

        // inicia a thread
        if (pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, thread_func, arg))
            printf("Error");

    }
}
```

If your inner loop runs more than once, you will overwrite the `pthread_t` of the first thread when you get the `pthread_t` of the second thread.

If you're going to create 16 threads, you need to write code that loops no more than 16 times creating threads. Your outer loop does loop 16 times. You need to move the inner loop to inside the thread.

Comment: Hi, David! For sure it's a problem. Thank you. 
But I think this is not the only problem, removing the second loop (putting j = 0 rather than the loop) dont stop the segfault.

Comment: The second loop also has only one iteration, I've put it to change the code for more in the future.

Comment: @AlcidesMignoso Can you update your question with the smallest possible complete, compilable code that seg faults?

Comment: The problem was solved removing the second loop and changing the index used in thread[i] to thread[i/step] in the main loop. Thank you :)